# How can I compare __FlashStringHelper* with char* on Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, string-comparison

I have a board that outputs lines of text to serial.  I need to compare these lines of text with ones I know.  Essentially, I'd like to do `strcmp(thestring,F("knownstring"))`, however there doesn't seem to be a version of strcmp that takes the FlashStringHelper* type.  There is strcmp_P that uses `const PROGMEM char *`, but that appears to be a different thing entirely.  Someone on an Arduino forum thread I saw suggested writing one by going through the flash-string with `progmem_read_byte (b, i)`, but that function doesn't actually exist and the nearest equivalent (`pgm_read_byte(b+i)`) doesn't seem to work with FlashStringHelper* - I get errors like `error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class __FlashStringHelper'` and `error: forward declaration of 'class __FlashStringHelper'`, which imply I've done something *seriously* wrong!  I'm nearly at a point of giving up and putting the strings in RAM instead, but the arduino doesn't have much of that so I want to avoid that if possible.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `__FlashStringHelper` is just special data type used for determining correct overloaded function/method for Flash strings.

Anyway you can't use `strcmp` as it's for comparing two strings in RAM, but in the include `<avr/pgmspace.h>` there is its variant `strcmp_P` for comparing `const char *` placed in RAM with `const char *` placed in FLASH memory (in this order).

So you can use either:

```
strcmp_P(thestring, (const char*)F("knownstring"));
// or better:
strcmp_P(thestring, PSTR("knownstring"));
```

The `F` macro is basically:  `(__FlashStringHelper *)PSTR("...")` so it's little bit redundant to cast it back to the `const char*` in the first case.

Comment: Should this work? I've got an example where `strcmp_P(thestring, (const char*)fstring)` fails, but works fine if I use `PSTR`.

Comment: I tried several variants and it works. For example:  `const auto fstring = F("BLABLA"); strcmp_P("inRam", (const char *)fstring);`