# How can I use __FlashStringHelper* in a function which takes char*?

Tags: c++, arduino, overloading

I managed to figure the answer to this out myself, but it took far too long. (I'm an arduino and C++ newbie).

Question:
How can I use strings written like `F("long string to store in flash memory instead of RAM")` (`__FlashStringHelper`) as if it were just a string like `"normal string"` (`const char*`).

E.g.

```
void doSomethingWithText(const char *text) {
   char* buffer[17];
   strncpy(buffer, text, 16); 
   Serial.println(buffer);
}
```

Where

```
doSomethingWithText("Use this text");  // WORKS
doSomethingWithText(F("Use this text instead");  // RAISES COMPILE ERROR
```

Compile Error:

> no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const __FlashStringHelper*'
> to 'const char*'

Note: I am aware that this question is similar to ([How can I compare __FlashStringHelper* with char* on Arduino?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334026/how-can-i-compare-flashstringhelper-with-char-on-arduino)), but it took me a long time to come across when I just wanted to know the answer to the question above.

Comment: important question is if you why do you want to read it to RAM? it is better to work with it from flash. there are many functions which can take string from flash. starting from sprintf_P and methods of Print class descendants Serial, WiFiClient, LCD, ...

Comment: @Juraj Good to keep in mind that it might not always be necessary to read it to RAM. In my real use case it is necessary, but in many simple cases it may be better to directly use functions which can take string from flash as you suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the function also work with the `F("...")`, add a function overload that takes `const __FlashStringHelper*` as an argument instead. e.g.

```
// This one stays the same
void doSomethingWithText(const char *text) {
   char* buffer[17];
   strncpy(buffer, text, 16);
   Serial.println(buffer);
}

// This will be used in the case where the argument is F("....")
void doSomethingWithText(const __FlashStringHelper *text) {
   char buffer[17];
   strncpy_P(buffer, (const char*)text, 16);  // _P is the version to read from program space
   Serial.println(buffer);
}
```

The three key parts are: overloading the function to account for the different argument type, using the `_P` version of various string functions, casting the `__FlashStringHelper` back to a `const char*`.

Note: For this simple case the `text` could be passed to `Serial.println(text)` directly.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a C-style cast instead of, say, `static_cast` or other C++ cast funcions?

Comment: @Mark, Good question, no good answer. I probably should have used a static_cast instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in **buffer** defenition. Star is excess in
`char* buffer[17];`

```
// This one stays the same
void doSomethingWithText(const char *text) {
   char buffer[17];
   strncpy(buffer, text, 16);
   Serial.println(buffer);
}

// This will be used in the case where the argument is F("....")
void doSomethingWithText(const __FlashStringHelper *text) {
   char buffer[17];
   strncpy_P(buffer, (const char*)text, 16);  // _P is the version to read from program space
   Serial.println(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated the answer. 
FYI, leaving a comment for a small change like that would have been more appropriate